# Android AdMob controlled by different Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, admob

I am developing a game for Android phones. I want to integrate Google AdMob ads into it, but make it as painless as possible for users. Basically, I want to only display ads when the game is Paused (I mean in-game pause)

I create the add inside the main activity

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Then I start a new Thread which keeps drawing on the canvas. On game pause (or game over), I am trying to show the ads (this is inside the newly created Thread)

```
adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
```

But I get the following exception

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
```

I am using GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access to view only from UI thread, use this:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
    }
}
runOnUiThread(runnable);
```

Or use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for that.

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
    };
};
```

and you could do this not in UI thread:

```
h.sendEmptyMessage(i);
```

i - simply any value that you can pass to handler, could be 0.

Edit:
The value passed to the handler(i) can be retrieved from the field msg.what

Comment: I tried replacing this line 

new Thread(new GameEngine(this)).start();

With this line

activity.runOnUiThread(new GameEngine(this));

But now my application does not start any more.

Comment: Okay, I managed to open a new UiThread that can show / hide the ads, but now how can I interact with it? If I make an infinite for loop inside the run() method, my app just stops

Comment: You could interact with UI thread through the handler, wait for a while, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You are awesome. Saved me lots of hours. I can't upvote your answer because I am new here, but it works perfectly! Thanks!